# Wood burning and carbon dioxide or monoxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am building greenhouse and i want to operate greenhouse at winter time. For heating i ll use wood. And also i am thinking to give back  carbon monoxide which ll come from burning process of wood. There is a question, how can avoid to get carbon monoxide from burning wood, do i must give more air flow (or oxygen flow) to burning process? Or when you burn wood there is just one gas output that is carbon dioxide?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35484/what-causes-incomplete-combustion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good reference to read is [Laboratory and field investigations of particulate and carbon monoxide emissions from traditional and improved cookstoves](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1352231008004895) Atmospheric Environment February 2009, Pages 1170–1181.

Unforntunately, there is a significant amount of carbon monoxide, from 29 to 118 grams of CO per kg of wood.

They find that the drier the wood, the less CO, but don't expect to completely eliminate CO.